# Problems including a jar into an OSGi bundle

Tags: gradle, jar, osgi, osgi-bundle

I have a gradle script (editor's cut):

```
apply plugin:'osgi'
apply plugin:'eclipse'
apply plugin:'groovy'

....

dependencies {
  ....
  compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.4'
  compile 'com.gmongo:gmongo:1.5'
}

jar {
  manifest {
      ....
      instruction 'Embed-Dependency', '*;scope=compile|runtime'
      instruction 'Embed-Transitive', 'true'
      instruction 'Bundle-ClassPath', '.,gmongo-1.5.jar'
  }

  from {
    configurations.compile.findAll{ !it.directory && it.name.startsWith( 'gmongo' ) }
  }
}
```

As soon as `gmongo` doesn't provide a proper bundle-manifest I must include it as a dependency.

The resulting jar structure is:

```
/
|..com/
|..META-INF/
|..gmongo-1.5.jar
```

MANIFEST.INF:

```
    Manifest-Version: 1.0
    Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
    Bnd-LastModified: 1461227335334
    Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
    Embed-Dependency: *;scope=compile|runtime
    Import-Package: com.gmongo,com.mongodb;version="[3.2,4)",groovy.lang;v
     ersion="[2.4,3)",....."
    Tool: Bnd-2.1.0.20130426-122213
    Export-Package: com.mozaiq.echo;version="1.0.0";uses:="com.gmongo,groo
     vy.lang,javax.servlet,javax.servlet.http,org.osgi.framework"
    Bundle-ClassPath: .,gmongo-1.5.jar
    Embed-Transitive: true
    Created-By: 1.8.0_72 (Oracle Corporation)
```

upon installing I'm getting

> ## 0   ERROR   > Error occurred while trying to resolve bundle groovyecho.jar.20160426-110910406.jar!
>
> org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Can't resolve groovyecho : package com.gmongo

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

even if I unpack the `gmongo.jar`'s classes:

```
jar {
  ....
  from {
    zipTree configurations.compile.find{ !it.directory && it.name.startsWith( 'gmongo' ) }
  }
}
```

I'm getting the same error.

SUMMARY:

```
instruction 'Import-Package', '!com.gmongo,*'
```

worked well for un-jared class files.

To make it work on original jar file, I had to add also

```
instruction 'Bundle-ClassPath', '.,gmongo-1.5.jar'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the manifest says com.gmongo must be imported. I suspect that the jar in the Bundle-Classpath is not being analyzed to see that it contains that package. So you will need to specify that the bundle does not need to import any needed packages from that embedded jar.

`Import-Package: !com.gmongo,*`

But given that you bundle exports com.mozaiq.echo which uses com.gmongo in its signature, you should probably export that package instead of stopping the import.

`-exportcontents: com.gmongo`

BTW, I don't think the `Embed-` instructions mean anything to the Gradle OSGi plugin which uses bnd. You can see they are just copied to the generated manifest. They are unique to the Apache Felix maven-bundle-plugin for Maven.

Comment: bingo! the `!com.gmongo` worked on unzipped class files. to make it work for the mongo.jar, I had to add `instruction 'Bundle-ClassPath', '.,gmongo-1.5.jar'`

Comment: The `Embed-Dependency` instruction is used by Bnd to calculate the imports of your bundle... so you don't need the `Import-Package` suggested in the answer...  as you're using the default Gradle `osgi` plugin, Bnd will not actually change the jar, just the manifest... that's why you still need to add the `from` instruction in the `jar` block to embed the jar, and add the `Bundle-ClassPath` instruction as well. If you want Bnd to do that, you can use the other [Gradle osgi plugin](https://github.com/TomDmitriev/gradle-bundle-plugin) by TomDmitriev.

Comment: `Embed-Dependency` is not something supported by bnd. It is something supported by the Apache Felix maven-bundle-plugin.